# Uniform initialization syntax for basic types?

Tags: c++, c++11, uniform-initialization

```
const int number{42};
```

Is this valid syntax? I can only find examples where the curly-brace initializers are used for objects or non-trivial types.

Comment: Why look for examples when you can just look it up in the language standard? Yes, it's allowed. That's what the "uniform" in "uniform" stands for.

Comment: The "uniform initialization syntax" is, well, *uniform*. So yes that's valid.

Comment: Well, I have used it already, and it works as expected, but then someone told me it's invalid syntax. So I went looking for examples. And here we are.

Comment: curly braces are used to initialize arrays, so your "number" variable is is just an array of 1 element. const.

Comment: @codekiddy Curly braces are used to initialize _anything_ (hence, "Uniform initialization"). `number` here is not an array; it is an `int`.

Comment: @hoosierEE What did you mean by "object?" `int`s are objects, too.

Comment: @StuartOlsen I guess I meant I've seen examples for non-intrinsic types (e.g. structs, vectors) but never for what I consider primitive types (e.g. int, double).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is **YES** it is allowed and it is a valid syntax.

You may check [Uniform initialization syntax and semantics](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init) by stroustrup

Also to add that as per C++98 8.5/13:

> If `T` is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form

```
T x = { a };
```

> is equivalent to

```
T x = a;
```

Comment: Okay, and what about `T x { a };` like in OP's question?

Comment: @FredOverflow:- Yes that is allowed as well!